# SqlFunctions.DatePart equivalent in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the equivalent of the following statement in EF Core?

```
SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", x.MyDate)
```

`EF.Functions` doesn't seem to have a `DatePart` method.

Comment: What `SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", x.MyDate)` returns?

Comment: SqlFunctions doesn't exist in .NET Core.

Comment: no direct way, but you can try  DateTime inputDate = DateTime.Parse(date.Trim());     
         CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;    
int weekNum = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(    
             inputDate,    
             CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,    
             DayOfWeek.Monday);

Comment: Week is exactly the one thing that .net's `DateTime` doesn't have. All other DateTime "part" properties, like `Year`, are translated to SQL's `DATEPART` function. But I guess that's why you ask about "week".

Answer (score 10):

For EF Core 5, it's even different as the `SqlFunctionExpression.Create` factory is now obsolete and the `SqlFunctionExpression` construction should be used instead. Here's the updated code (if adding it to the DB Context):

```cs
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTimeOffset? date) => throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DatePart)} cannot be called client side.");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(DbFunctionExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DatePart));

        var datePartMethodInfo = typeof(ApplicationDbContext) // Your DB Context
            .GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(ApplicationDbContext.DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTimeOffset) });
        builder.HasDbFunction(datePartMethodInfo)
           .HasTranslation(args =>
                    new SqlFunctionExpression("DATEPART",
                        new[]
                        {
                            new SqlFragmentExpression((args.ToArray()[0] as SqlConstantExpression).Value.ToString()),
                            args.ToArray()[1]
                        },
                        true,
                        new[] { false, false },
                        typeof(int?),
                        null
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can switch to `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset` as per your needs.

(The exception has nothing to do with EF Core 5, it's just more clear for anybody working on the code later on or trying to call the method client side).

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to make use of the datepart SQL function by wrapping it with the DbFunctionAttribute.
Tricky part is to tell ef core not to handle the datepart type parameter as a string. Example:

DbContext `ef core <= 2.1`:

```cs
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(nameof(DatePart), typeof(int?), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }));
}
```

DbContext `ef core >= 3.1` (static `SqlFunctionExpression.Create` call instead of ctor):

```cs
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create(nameof(DatePart), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }, typeof(int?), null));
}
```

Query:

```cs
repository.Where(x => dbContext.DatePart("week", x.CreatedAt) > 10);
```

some more info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10404

watch out not to call the DbFunction method on an interface of DbContext. The call must happend directly on the DbContext instance.

Edit: for `ef core 3.1` you can use the static method `SqlFunctionExpression.Create` instead of the ctor:

Comment: I can't create the SqlFragmentExpression instance, the constructor is internal O_o

Comment: This has been fixed: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/18208

Comment: oh, I see, thanks. I guess there is still no other way to do this than this, right? Is there anyone working on adding these features?

Comment: The new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()) results in [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression]

Answer (score 3):

for ef core 3.1 is little different solution, should cast argument first to `SqlConstantExpression` then pass its `Value` to `SqlFragmentExpression` constructor:

```cs
public static class DbFunctionExtensions
{
    public static int? DatePart(string type, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

    public static void ConfigureDbFunctions(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var mi = typeof(DbFunctionExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DatePart));

        modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(mi, b => b.HasTranslation(e =>
        {
            var ea = e.ToArray();
            var args = new[]
            {
                new SqlFragmentExpression((ea[0] as SqlConstantExpression).Value.ToString()),
                ea[1]
            };
            return SqlFunctionExpression.Create(nameof(DatePart), args, typeof(int?), null);
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gene-R, I am trying to get this working using EF Core 3.1. I can make the call but am getting a could not be translated error.I am calling the above with  ... "DbFunctionExtensions.DatePart("w", a.ReferenceDate) ==2" in a where. Any help much appreciated

Comment: shouldn't be `DbFunctionExtensions.DatePart("week", a.ReferenceDate)` ? Also i am checking column for NULL before using datepart

Answer (score 1):

For .net 8.0 Ef 8.0 use this

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTimeOffset? date) => throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DatePart)} cannot be called client side.");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(DbFunctionExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DatePart));

        var datePartMethodInfo = typeof(ApplicationDbContext) // Your DB Context
            .GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(ApplicationDbContext.DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTimeOffset) });
        builder.HasDbFunction(datePartMethodInfo)
           .HasTranslation(args =>
                    new SqlFunctionExpression("DATEPART",
                        new[]
                        {
                            new SqlFragmentExpression((args.ToArray()[0] as SqlConstantExpression).Value.ToString()),
                            args.ToArray()[1]
                        },
                        true,
                        new[] { false, false },
                        typeof(int?),
                        null
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

for .net 6.0 ef 6.15 use this

```
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create(nameof(DatePart), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }, typeof(int?), null));
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who gets `...returns a SqlExpression of type 'int?', which is a nullable value type...` change the 2x `int?` to `int` and it works!