# EF Core Implement sql server DATEPART as DbFunction static method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add the DATEPART sql-server function to Entity Framework Core by adding it as a static method on DbContext with the [DbFunction] attribute as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0

The problem is that sql-server receives the datepart parameter as a string and it cant run it because the datepart parameter can't be a string (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "Note DATEPART does not accept user-defined variable equivalents for the datepart arguments.")

i have also tried removing the double quotes from the argument i pass to datepart, by doing sting.Replace("\"", "") but it still does not work (it change the argument from "'arg'" to 'arg')

Here is my code:

```
[DbFunction("DATEPART","")]
public static int DATEPART(string datepart, DateTime date)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Is there any other data type that will work? am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any way to use that function with EF Core other than writing manual SQL.

Comment: You could define a UDF that wraps datepart, then call the UDF from your code. The query compiler should inline the function call so there should be no performance impact.

Comment: @Dai you mean a function in sql-server and that function will call DATEPART, but i  in code will call my custom function

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What would the code look like.  If you're trying to change the value type (datetime to int) before c#, you're doing it in the wrong place.  If you're trying to use it for a where clause, your schema is bad.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have two tables in database that i need to query where tableA is in the week of tableB, that why i am trying to use DATEPART wk, i can't add a stored procedure to the database, is there any other way i can so thanks? tnk

Comment: I'd probably just create a view.

Comment: @ErikPhilips tnx for your reply, another reason why i need it to be in code not in DB is because i need to construct the filter at run time based on the user selection, so there is a UI that the user can apply any filter they want and i am adding Where clauses to an IQueryable - sorry for not explaining in the beginning

Comment: @Dai I created a UDF that takes a date and return like this: RETURN DATEPART(week, @date), the performance desecrated dramatically (from 2 seconds to 25), am i doing something wrong with the way the UDF is defined?, i dont have much experience with scalar function performance, but a basic google search shows that it could hurt performance, any help much appropriate

Comment: @JoelG Can you post some example queries? I suspect you're running into issues with SARGability.

Comment: could you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up doing it with row sql and it works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SqlFunctions.DatePart equivalent in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529454/sqlfunctions-datepart-equivalent-in-ef-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make use of the datepart SQL function by wrapping it with the DbFunctionAttribute.
Tricky part is to tell ef core not to handle the datepart type parameter as a string. Example:

DbContext:

```cs
public int? DatePart(string datePartArg, DateTime? date) => throw new Exception();

public void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(DbContext).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(DatePart), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) });
    modelBuilder
        .HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
        .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(nameof(DatePart), typeof(int?), new[]
                {
                        new SqlFragmentExpression(args.ToArray()[0].ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                }));
}
```

Query:

```cs
repository.Where(x => dbContext.DatePart("weekday", x.CreatedAt) == DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

some more info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10404